# Prevent from resizing web sites below limit

Tags: html, css

Can anybody help me how prevent web site not to go under 320px when I minimize window of browser? The minimum width of the website I would need 320px.

The HTML and CSS code can be found here:

http://kod.djpw.cz/huqc

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, would be nice if you could edit your question so that it would contain a minimal, complete and verifiable example - see this link for more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Just add `min-width: 320px` in your `body` css. Will resolve your issue.

```
body {
   min-width: 320px;
}
```

Comment: @JosephCloude If the answer help you out, please marked as correct. Thanks